# How to tell if return is JSONObject or JSONArray with JSON-simple (Java)?

Tags: java, json, types, json-simple

I am hitting a service and sometimes getting back something like this:

```
{ "param1": "value1", "param2": "value2" }
```

and sometimes getting return like this:

```
[{ "param1": "value1", "param2": "value2" },{ "param1": "value1", "param2": "value2" }]
```

How do I tell which I'm getting? Both of them evaluate to a String when I do getClass() but if I try to do this:

```
json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(result);
```

on the second case I get an exception

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

How to avoid this? I would just like to know how to check which I'm getting back. (The first case will sometimes have `[]` in it so I can't do index of and I'd like a cleaner way than just checking the first character.

There has got to be some sort of method that checks this?

Comment: It should be pretty simple to check if the string begins and ends with `[]`. What have you tried?

Comment: I can tell if it beings and ends with [] but then the problem is that i get a string "[{\"param1\"...},{...}]" that I can't seem to convert into an array again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simple Java:

```
Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(result); 
if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
} else {
    JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) obj;
}
```

You could also test if the (purported) JSON starts with a `[` or a `{` if you wanted to avoid the overhead of parsing the wrong kind of JSON.  But be careful with leading whitespace.

---

For what it is worth, an API that returns either a JSON object or an array of JSON objects depending on the result set size is ... badly designed.  It would be better to *always* return a JSON array; e.g. an array containing zero, one or many objects.  That avoids the client-side messiness we are having to deal with in this question.

Comment: Thanks. That answered my question. Now to figure out the rest of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Though it's similar to above one, but their is not default constructor of JSONParser. Error coming was: The constructor JSONParser() is undefined

Use this instead

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
    //Your Code
} else {
    //Your Code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing Json version